# How to pass raw HTML string through array_map in php ignoring HTML tags

Tags: php, string, array-map

For the below program, I want to output the strings as they are in `$a`, but in my case they are being converted to html format. How can I bypass the conversion.

```
<?php
function myfunction($v)
{
    return $v;
}

$a=array("<p>Horse</p>","<a>Dog</a>","<h1>Cat</h1>");
print_r(array_map("myfunction",$a));
?>
```

Output of above program-

```
Array ( [0] =>
Horse

[1] => Dog [2] =>
**Cat**
)
```

Comment: how do you mean 'html format'? html is just text.

Comment: What do you mean? https://3v4l.org/Dbf5p

Comment: htmlspecialchars or htmlentities

Comment: I checked the code on this editor - http://phpfiddle.org/#

Comment: Rendering is done by the browser, not PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `htmlentities()` in your function:

```
function myfunction($v) {
    return htmlentities($v);
}
```

This will replace all the `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `gt;`, along with various other replacements, so when you send the output to the browser it will render them as the original special characters.